# Arch Linux install works, but grub doesn't

Tags: grub, arch-linux

I've just installed Arch Linux onto my shiny new computer (ASUS ROG motherboard) and while the installation and configuration of Grub went off without issue, attempting to boot the system fails.  Basically you turn the thing on, it shows the boot logo, then dumps you into the BIOS.

Stuff you'd want to know:

- The system is BIOS, not EFI/GPT.  The motherboard supports EFI, but it came to me with Windows 10 pre-installed on an msdos-partitioned disk and I just repartitioned it rather than wipe Windows off it.
- The primary hard drive is one of these new-fangled NVME drives.  It appears as /dev/nvme0n1 in Linux.
- The drive has 4 partitions.  These 3 Windows partitions were there when I got it.  I just resized the 3rd one to make room for Linux:

  - HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  - HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  - Hidden NTFS WinRE
  - Linux
- The Linux partition is formatted with ext4
- Grub was installed with `grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/nvme0n1`
- When I boot from the USB stick in non-efi mode (the BIOS has an option for this) I have the option to `Boot existing OS`.  When I select this it fails.  **However**, if I hit `tab` to edit the disk and partition number and set it to `hd2 0` **it works**.  I get Grub and if I hit enter, everything boots as it should.
- The BIOS has a toggle for `Windows EFI` vs. `Other OS`.  I've selected the latter and disabled Secure Boot.
- This system was running Gentoo Linux for about 8months until today when I tried to switch distros.

I did some poking around the Grub command line following [this tutorial](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux) and everything works as expected.  I can `set root=(hd2,0)` etc. and the system boots fine.  I just can't get my box to recognise Grub at boot time.  I can only get it to work by booting off a USB stick.

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fighting, I decided to go the nuclear route:

1. Use the Arch install USB stick to get a Grub prompt
2. Use that prompt to get my computer to boot into Windows 10
3. In Windows 10, I used Microsoft's tools to create a Windows 10 install USB stick
4. I booted from this new stick and overwrote my whole disk, repartitioning and leaving space for Linux.
5. With the new Windows installation now running on EFI/GPT, I did a normal Arch Linux install installing Grub on the EFI partition.